# OkHttp with Gson (POST) issue

Tags: android, post, gson, okhttp

This is the query that I have to perform:

```
http://example.com/webservice/?value=
    [{
         "table": "images",
          "operation": "insert",
          "params": [
            {
              "color_id": 2 ,        
              "name": "yellow" 
            }
          ],
          "transactionCompleted": true
        }]
```

But I'm not able to do that from an Android app. I'm using `OkHttp` and `Gson`. Take a look at the code below. When using the debugger I see that everything is fine but still the values are not inserted. Any help will be appreciated.

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

JsonArray form = new JsonArray();
JsonObject item = new JsonObject();

item.addProperty("table", "images");
item.addProperty("operation", "insert");

JsonArray params = new JsonArray();
JsonObject paramItem = new JsonObject();
paramItem.addProperty("color_id", colorId);
paramItem.addProperty("name", name);
params.add(paramItem);
item.add("params", params);
item.addProperty("transactionCompleted", true);
form.add(item);

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MIME_JSON, new Gson().toJson(form));
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                        .url("http://www.example.com/webservice/?value=")
                        .post(body)
                        .build();

                okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Can you clarify `When I enter this in the browser it is actually inserting the values`? IMO, in the browser, it's GET request, not POST

Comment: my mistake, I didnt know

Comment: can I do the inserting with GET? is that wrong ?

Comment: I think you can check your server side (web service), however, should use POST to insert data

Comment: Im really stuck here, how can I do this with GET?

Comment: use postman extension for chrome with that you can perform post request too

Comment: @Bhargov can you show me an example

Comment: @BNK How can i change this to GET ?

Comment: As I said, you should use POST. Are you sure your web service supports GET to insert data? Post its code or specification.

Comment: @BNK Yes Im sure, and I ended up with adding the JSON to the url of the GET request and it works now

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the JSON in the url. I know its not a convenient way. But it worked. I hope somebody will find this useful.

```
public class example {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        String run(String url) throws IOException {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();
        }
    }
JsonArray form = new JsonArray();
JsonObject item = new JsonObject();

item.addProperty("table", "images");
item.addProperty("operation", "insert");

JsonArray params = new JsonArray();
JsonObject paramItem = new JsonObject();
paramItem.addProperty("color_id", colorId);
paramItem.addProperty("name", name);
params.add(paramItem);
item.add("params", params);
item.addProperty("transactionCompleted", true);
form.add(item);
 response = example.run("http://www.example.com/webservice/?value=" + new Gson().toJson(form));
```